# How can I resolve a gpfs stale file handle in centos7

Tags: centos, mount

I'm trying to get some multicluster thing working between two of our GPFS clusters. One is a storage cluster like `gpfs01` and another is compute cluster like `gpfs02`.

In the "`gpfs02`" cluster I created `mmremotecluster` and `mmremotefs` is configured correctly, but when trying to mount, I get this stale file handle error:

```
[root@gpfs02 ~]# mmmount all

Thu Dec 12 18:57:14 IST 2019: mmmount: Mounting file systems ...

mount: mount gpfs02 on /gpfs/storage failed: Stale file handle.
```

but trying `mmlsmount` I get this:

```
[root@gpfs02 ~]# mmlsmount all -L

File system gpfs02 (gpfs01:gpfs01) is mounted on 1 nodes:

192.168.1.215   gpfs01                    gpfs01        

[root@gpfs02 ~]# mmlsmount all_remote

File system gpfs02 (gpfs01:gpfs01) is mounted on 1 nodes.

[root@gpfs02 ~]# tail -f 100 /var/adm/ras/mmfs.log.latest
```

shows

```
tail: cannot open '100' for reading: No such file or directory
==> /var/adm/ras/mmfs.log.latest <== 2019-12-12_19:08:47.793+0530: [E] Disk failure.  Volume gpfs02. rc = 19. Physical volume nsd3.
2019-12-12_19:08:47.793+0530: [E] Disk failure.  Volume gpfs02. rc = 19. Physical volume nsd4.
2019-12-12_19:08:47.794+0530: [X] File System gpfs02 unmounted by the system with return code 19 reason code 0, at line 483 in /project/sprelttn423/build/rttn423s008a/src/avs/fs/mmfs/ts/stripe/stripeopen.C
2019-12-12_19:08:47.794+0530: No such device
2019-12-12_19:08:47.794+0530: Failed to open gpfs02.
2019-12-12_19:08:47.794+0530: No such device
2019-12-12_19:08:47.794+0530: [E] Failed to open gpfs02.
2019-12-12_19:08:47.794+0530: [W] Command: err 666: mount gpfs02
2019-12-12_19:08:47.794+0530: No such device
2019-12-12_19:08:47.855+0530: mmcommon preunmount invoked.  File system: gpfs01  Reason: SGPanic
2019-12-12_19:14:21.440+0530: [I] Leaving remote cluster gpfs01
2019-12-12_19:14:21.441+0530: [I] Cluster Manager connection broke. Probing cluster gpfs01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create disk below the steps:

1) sdb :
dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdb count=10240 bs=64k

sdc :
dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdc count=10240 bs=64k

2) need to create vim stanza.nsds file

%nsd: device=/sdb

nsd=nsd3

servers=gpfs01

usage=dataOnly

failureGroup=100

pool=data

%nsd: device=/sdc

nsd=nsd4

servers=gpfs01

usage=dataOnly

failureGroup=100

pool=data

3) after that create disk :

mmcrnsd -F stanza.nsds -v no

3) mmlsnsd

### File system   Disk name    NSD servers

(free disk)   nsd3        gpfs01
 (free disk)   nsd4        gpfs01

4) create file system and mount point.